# What is a good pratrice when trying to access child methods from a parent static type object?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm having a problem with inheritance. I've illustrated it with those account classes :

```
class Account {
    accountLevel = BASIC;
    connect() {...}
    changePassword() { ... }
    ChangeEmail() { ... }
}

class CustomerAccount extends Account {
    accountLevel = CUSTOMER;
    createOrder() { ... }
    payOrder() { ... }
}

class AdminAccount extends Account {
    accountLevel = ADMIN;
    addProduct() { ... }
    deleteProduct() { ... }
}
```

If I have an instance of an Account and I want to cast it to a AdminAccount to do addProduct() is it okay to do that :

```
Account account = new AdminAccount();
if(account.accountLevel == ADMIN){
    AdminAccount adminAccount = (AdminAccount) account;
    adminAccount.addProduct();
}
```

Edit:
I want to have all my accounts in the same List, because they all use the same connect method. But when the account is connected I still have an account object but I want to use their dynamic type methods, so i'm forced to cast the object.

It's almost like an `instanceof` but with extra steps. I feel like having to cast the account isn't very OOP, is there another more elegant solution ? Maybe not use inheritance between the accounts classes ?

Comment: Why are you trying different account types in a generic way? Generally, only the code that performs general operations receive base type instances, while more specialized methods receive the specific instances

Comment: So would you recommand to have only one Account class with all the methods in it. And they could send an Exception if the level access isn't high enough ? That way their is no issue with inheritance, but is it less oop ?

Comment: In general, I try to avoid inheritance. Over time, it really messes everything up and makes every change more difficult. But this is just an opinion. You'll find other opinions out there, and they are all as valid as mine. In the end, it's a matter of taste

Comment: So you have all the accounts mixed in a list. Why? How did they end up there? You might want to take a look at the visitor pattern, that's the correct way to avoid if statements by some type attribute or instanceof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's considered not to be a good practice to have `if` statements by some type attribute or by `instanceof` checks.

An alternative to this is the [**visitor pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Here's a sketch of what you could do:

```
interface IAccount {
    void process(AccountProcessor processor);
}

interface AccountProcessor {

    void processBasicAccount(Account acc);

    void processCustomerAccount(CustomerAccount acc);

    void processAdminAccount(AdminAccount acc);
}
```

The idea is that you have an interface that defines a `process` method for all the accounts, that receives an `AccountProcessor` (you can change the names here, this is just to show an example). There should be one method for every different type of account. You could even use *method overloading*, i.e. all methods could be named something like `processAccount` and receive a specialized account type.

Now, your `Account` class and all its subtypes should implement the `IAccount` interface:

```
class Account implements IAccount {

    @Override
    void process(AccountProcessor processor) {
       processor.processBasicAccount(this);
    }

    // all the other Account stuff
}

class CustomerAccount implements IAccount {

    @Override
    void process(AccountProcessor processor) {
       processor.processCustomerAccount(this);
    }

    // all the other CustomerAccount stuff
}

class AdminAccount implements IAccount {

    @Override
    void process(AccountProcessor processor) {
       processor.processAdminAccount(this);
    }

    // all the other AdminAccount stuff
}
```

Now, with all these pieces in place, you are ready to process your list of accounts:

```
class AccountProcessorImpl implements AccountProcessor {

    private List<Account> accounts; // filled with all the accounts

    void doSomethingWithAllTheAccounts() {

        // iterate all the accounts and process each one of them
        accounts.forEach(IAccount::process);
    }

    @Override
    public void processBasicAccount(Account acc) {
       // do something with the basic account
    }

    @Override
    public void processCustomerAccount(CustomerAccount acc) {
       // do something with the customer account
    }

    @Override
    public void processAdminAccount(AdminAccount acc) {
       // do something with the admin account
    }
}
```

I hope you grasp the general idea. This is just a sketch to show you the core technique. There might be variants, i.e. you might have separate processors for each different type of account, or you might process the list of accounts in a class other than the `AccountProcessorImpl`, etc.

Comment: But that would mean I have some methods with nothing in them. Wouldn't that be a problem too ?

Comment: @Ateatwe You should implement the methods

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is:

```
AdminAccount account = new AdminAccount();
account.addProduct();
```

If the expectation is only an Admin Account can add a product, relevant methods should expect an Admin Account in the input instead of an account. Is there a reason the instance is being created as an Account instead of an Admin Account?

Edit - Including sample packaging type handling into a manager class.

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        AccountManager manager = new AccountManager();
        manager.addAccount(new User());
        manager.addAccount(new User());
        manager.addAccount(new Admin());
        System.out.println(manager.getUsers().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    public static final class AccountManager
    {
        private final List<Account> allAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
        public Stream<User> getUsers(){ return getAccountType(User.class); }
        public Stream<Admin> getAdmins(){ return getAccountType(Admin.class); }
        public Stream<Account> getAccounts(){ return getAccountType(Account.class); }
        public <T extends Account> void addAccount(T account) { if(account.connect()) allAccounts.add(account); }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") private <T> Stream<T> getAccountType(Class<T> type){ return allAccounts.stream().filter(type::isInstance).map(act -> (T) act); }
    }

    public static final class User extends Account{}
    public static final class Admin extends Account{}
    public static class Account { boolean connect(){ return true; } }
```

Comment: I want to have all my accounts in the same List, because they all use the same connect method. But when the account is connected and I want to use their dynamic type methods, i'm forced to cast the object. It doesn't seems to be very oop

Comment: It may be worth updating the question with these details. One option to address this is to add a AccountManager class which handles each of the account types. It can be ok to cast to a subtype, but generally this logic should be packaged to avoid misuse. Including a sample above.

Answer (score 0):

It's really OK. We call it polymorphism in OOP. Parents can be cast to all children.